# How do I upgrade my chirpy blog from the current state?

Tags: jekyll, blogs, mermaid

I just uploaded [a post](https://galenseilis.github.io/posts/car-simpy-ciw/) to my blog. I see this message

[image]

Here is the code for the diagram:

```
---
title: Car Example
---
stateDiagram-v2
    [*] --> Parked
    Parked --> Driving: 5
    Driving --> Parked: 2
    Parked --> [*]
    Driving --> [*]
```

The code for the mermaid diagram should be valid since it renders fine in Obsidian:

[image]

Looking at my Gem file and `_config.yml` I didn't see anything that looked like a version for mermaid or for the Chirpy theme.

I tried following [these instructions](https://www.richardn.ca/posts/UpdatingChirpy/) but [it didn't build](https://github.com/galenseilis/galenseilis.github.io/actions/runs/7284931362/job/19851025057). I'm not sure why. The errors appear to be related to my media files, which didn't cause a problem before.

What should be my next steps for upgrading my blog?

---

Update:

I reverted my chirpy version back to what it was before (see [commit history](https://github.com/galenseilis/galenseilis.github.io/commits/main/) for details) and updated the mermaid code to:

```
stateDiagram
    [*] --> Parked
    Parked --> Driving: 5
    Driving --> Parked: 2
    Parked --> [*]
    Driving --> [*]
```

So when you look at my blog (post link above) you can see a diagram (*sans* the title).

That will be okay for that post, but I should still learn how to fully update my software versions of my blog.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, I cannot access your build log any longer. It seems Chirpy loads the mermaid JS here: https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy/blob/master/_includes/mermaid.html